# Ошибка "Точка входа в процедуру GetCurrentThreadStackLimits не найдена в библиотеке DLL KERNEL32.dll" в Windows 7

Tags: php, windows

Когда в cmd я ввожу php --version или запускаю php код в IDE, у меня появляется ошибка Windows: "Точка входа в процедуру GetCurrentThreadStackLimits не найдена в библиотеке DLL KERNEL32.dll.". С чем связана эта ошибка и как её устранить на Windows 7 64x и с php версии 8.3.1?

Answer (score 3):

Как сказано в руководстве по миграции на версию 8.3, [Минимальная поддерживаемая версия Windows увеличена до Windows 8 или Windows Server 2012](https://www.php.net/manual/ru/migration83.windows-support.php).

То есть напрямую запустить 8.3 в Win 7 не получится. Надо либо ставить 8.2, либо менять ОС, либо запускать РНР в виртуальном окружении, например через docker.